# Dense domain of Unbounded Operator

Tags: operator-theory

Let $H$ a Hilbert space and $A:D(A)\subsetneq H\rightarrow H$ a dissipative, unbounded linear operator with $R(A)=Im(A)$ closed in $H$, such that exist $A^{-1}$, bounded linear operator. How I can prove that $D(A)$ is dense in $H$.

Answer (score 0):

I think $A$ considered as an operator in $H \bigoplus H'$ (where $H'$ is another Hilbert space) satisfies the same conditions with respect to $H \bigoplus H'$. But $D(A)$ is not dense in $H \bigoplus H'$